# Arrays in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm just getting started with Selenium IDE - completely new.

The issue: how to retrieve array values when the array was created by

```
execute script | var array1 = document.getElementsByClassName("Post"); return array1; | array1
```

Then I thought it made sense to return values with a For each statement

```
For each | ${array1} | iterator
echo | ${array1}[$iterator]
```

But it clearly isn't the right syntax as it just skips straight over it. If I echo the array object itself it returns [Object object] so I know that it's creating the Array alright. What's the appropriate way to retrieve Array values?

I've been knocking my head off a wall trying to understand the syntax in the Selenium Chrome IDE. The Documentation is very sparse and most material seems to reference an older version of the tool.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. The correct syntax for your `For each` loop is:

`For each | array1 | iterator`

`echo | ${iterator}`

Learn more about Selenium IDE arrays [here](https://sitegrammar.com/selenium-ide-arrays/).

Comment: In this case, does that mean you can reference say for example index 5 of the array using the iterator variable?
`${iterator[4]}`
I need to iterator over the entire array but also pull individual values too.

Comment: One solution could be to access the array value directly like this: `echo | ${array1[1]}`

Comment: That still returns [Object Object]

Comment: Are you sure that you are initializing your array properly? Does the for each loop return the correct values?

Comment: It returns an object which is expected but I need a way to access the objects first key. So think 2D arrays `  [0][0] , [0][1] `